# Get a parameter from NSURL

Tags: ios, nsurl

In my application I need to get parameters "access_token" and "user_id" from this url :
 https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=b1b33dfaa3&expires_in=86400&user_id=311515

Here is My code for accessing the "user_id" parameter in webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
NSArray *userAr = [[[[webView request] URL] absoluteString] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&user_id="];

NSString *user_id = [userAr lastObject];
```

How do I get the "access_token"? If I use the same method it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to understand the code. `componentsSeparatedByString` creates an array of smaller strings that are separated by `&user_id=`. This means, the output for you would be:

```
Array of ["https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=b1b33dfaa3&expires_in=86400", "311515"]
```

Now you see why the `lastObject` gets you the value of `user_id`. Now try to use the same methods to get the value of `access_token`.

Hint: you need to set `&` as the separator.

Answer (score 1):

The same functionality i have implemented in my application also.

If you are using webView to use this

```
NSURL* url = [[webView request] URL];

NSString *string =  [[url absoluteString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@"&"]; (here it's tweak to chnage '#' to '&')

NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
NSLog(@"queryParams %@", components);
```

Basically we need to divide our `URL in to two sub-part` , according this you will get `main url and other part as list of parameter`.`

Here you will get all the parameter related to your `URL`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I thin these code will help you:

```
NSArray *query = @"https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=b1b33dfaa3&expires_in=86400&user_id=311515 ";
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSString *param in [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"]) {
    NSArray *parts = [param componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    if([parts count] < 2) continue;
    [params setObject:[parts objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[parts objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```